# How to plot the sum of a specific row id

Tags: r, ggplot2

i have some tables like this

```
Location  Profit
Europe    8000
Asia      3200
Africa    4000
Americas  1800
Europe    3200
Europe    8000
Asia      3200
Oceania   1000
Africa    4000
Europe    3200
Europe    8000
Asia      3200
Africa    4000
Europe    3200
```

and i want to create a plot what will combine all profits from region "Europe".

how can i do this with ggplot?

Comment: What kind of a plot? A bar plot?

Comment: Hello @RuiBarradas, yeah a bar plot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to plot the totals of a column grouped by another column, you can use `aggregate` first.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(aggregate(Profit ~ Location, dat, sum), aes(Location, Profit)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

Note that you could also compute the aggregated data.frame first, and then use the result `agg` in the call to `ggplot`.

```
agg <- aggregate(Profit ~ Location, dat, sum)
```

**DATA**

```
dat <-
structure(list(Location = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 
3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("Africa", "Americas", 
"Asia", "Europe", "Oceania"), class = "factor"), Profit = c(8000L, 
3200L, 4000L, 1800L, 3200L, 8000L, 3200L, 1000L, 4000L, 3200L, 
8000L, 3200L, 4000L, 3200L)), .Names = c("Location", "Profit"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -14L))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I have only one question regarding the data. You are doing a lot of concatenations for example in the regions which with my example it is easy. but if i had 1.000.000  regions, then what?

Comment: @akalogiros If you had 1.000.000 regions, you would get a graph with 1.000.000 bars! Which is unreadable. Would you want a graph with one bar for region "Europe" and another bar for all others?

Comment: sorry for coming back on this. I can't understand why you did this concatenation(4L,3L,1L,2L etc). What does "L" means?

Comment: `4L` means that it is a number of class `"integer"`. Try `class(4L)` and compare with `class(4)`. Note that this comes from the column `Location`, a vector of class `factor`. R factors are categorical variables and are coded internally as integer numbers starting with `1L`.

Comment: can you please propose me a good course for R?Beginner level.

Comment: That will depend on where you are. I believe you should look it up for yourself.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to @RuiBarradas method, we can also use `stat_summary`

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(Location, Profit)) + 
       stat_summary(fun.y = "sum", geom = "bar")
```

[image]